# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't see my web camera. Help me please

Tags: drivers, kernel, webcam

There is a problem with my camera. I used Ubuntu 16.04 and this OS could see my web camera. Then I changed my OS to Ubuntu 18.04 and now it doesn't see the web cam. What's the problem? I also tried both 16.04 and 18.04 liveCD and only the first one sees my web cam.

`4.15.0-29-generic #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 18 08:54:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` **works correctly with the camera.**
`4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` **doesn't.**

How to stay on Ubuntu 18.04 to use my camera? Any suggestions please?
The OS determine my cam as `Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0ac8:307b Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. USB 1.1 Webcam`
My cam is `Canyon CNR-WCAM43G`

There is a possibility that the developers did not include the old drivers for the new kernel version and IDK why.
Skype and Cheese don't see the cam as well. I tried the commands `cheese` and `cheese /dev/video0`

```
    user@user1:~$ cheese

(cheese:5334): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:45:42.851: Theme parsing error: cheese.css:7:35: The style property GtkScrollbar:min-slider-length is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
** Message: 21:45:42.931: cheese-application.vala:211: Error during camera setup: No device found


(cheese:5334): cheese-CRITICAL **: 21:45:42.943: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:5334): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:45:42.943: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:5334): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:45:42.943: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 21:45:42.943: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5334): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:45:42.943: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 21:45:42.943: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:5334): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:45:42.943: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:5334): CRITICAL **: 21:45:42.943: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed

    user@user1:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0ac8:307b Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. USB 1.1 Webcam
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

    user@user1:~$ ls -ll /dev/video*
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root video 81, 0 feb 25 09:48 /dev/video0

$ sudo modprobe -r gspca       
sudo: modprbe: command not found
$ sudo modprobe -r zc0301
modprobe: FATAL: Module zc0301 not found.
$ sudo modprobe gspca
modprobe: FATAL: Module gspca not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic
```

Comment: What's the output of `lsusb` and `ls-ll /dev/video*` ? Please edit the question with that.

Answer (score 1):

A little search and I found this bug on lauchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/144745

The proposed solution is to unload 2 modules and reload it

```
sudo modprobe -r gspca
sudo modprobe -r zc0301
sudo modprobe gspca
```

A permanent fix would then be to blacklist the **zc0301** module. Create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-zc0301.conf` with this content

```
blacklist zc0301
```

Comment: It is `modprobe` not `modprbe` ... I have edited the answer ...

Comment: I did what you said. You can see the result in the OPost.

Comment: sudo modprobe -r gspca - modprobe: FATAL: Module gspca not found

Comment: Yes, I tried modprobe too. The module is not in the system

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off Secure Boot. For my Dell laptop, I hold F2 while it's booting to enter BIOS. Then look around for the option to disable Secure Boot.